# Como gerar valores padrões com JPA hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Gostaria de otimizar meu código e meu trabalho com a seguinte situação.
Tenho uma entidade endereço que tem possui um tipo, ou seja, uma outra entidade chamada TpEndereco. Sendo que, esta tabela tem valores padrões, exemplo: comercial, outro, residencial...

Gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de inicializar esse valores ao iniciar a aplicação e ainda poder inserir novos registro na mesma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Até a última vez que conferi não havia na especificação do JPA nada sobre carga de dados, isto é, algum padrão para inserir valores nas tabelas automaticamente.

Especificamente o Hibernate possui uma configuração [`hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#configuration-misc-properties) que permite especificar arquivos SQL que serão executados no momento da criação do banco de dados. Note que isso só vai funcionar se o tipo de criação do banco for `create` ou `create-drop`, na propriedade `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`.

Entretanto, não recomendaria usar essa função por vários motivos:

- O conteúdo é específico para cada banco de dados
- A estrutura dos inserts pode ficar diferente das suas classes
- Isso só funciona na criação do banco, não tem como atualizar ou adicionar valores

Para produção, uma solução mais especializada é melhor. O mais básico seria você mesmo desenvolver uma rotina executada na inicialização no sistema e que insere valores caso não existam.

Fora isso existem diversas alternativas mais avançadas para versionar bancos de dados. Alguns exemplos:

- [Inicialização usando Spring Framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html)
- Usar uma ferramenta de migrações como [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/) ou [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/)

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda! É que eu vi no Framework do Demosielle havia essa opção, pensei que poderia haver algo nativo no JPA. Mas obrigado pelo esclarecimento.